# Faceted search on client side

Tags: javascript

Can you suggest a basic faceted search library use at client (browser) side.

I quickly looked through [exhibit3](https://github.com/zepheira/exhibit3), but looks heavy for my usage. It mentioned somewhere that exhibit3 can be used on client side alone, but the setup mentioned a backstage project in java.

http://www.simile-widgets.org/exhibit3/examples/nobelists/nobelists.html

Above is an example usage I am looking for (only the category search, no time line view, etc). If it can group data and allow faceted search from json file (independent of backend), that will suit my purpose.

### EDIT:

Found a good walk through of one of the exhibit example [here](http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Sample_Exhibit_HTML_Text).
It pulls lot of dependencies, and wish there a minified version (ready to use :-) ). Anyone uses this for client only solution for relatively medium size data.

Answer (score 3):

facetedsearch.js looks like it would be appropriate.  Find it here: http://eikes.github.com/facetedsearch/ or skip the fancy site and go straight to the code: https://github.com/eikes/facetedsearch/